# How to send latitude and Longitude from one user to another user - android

Tags: android, ios, node.js, location, socket.io

I just want to create an app, which send location detail of one user to another user continuously till the meet. i'm plan to make this app in iOS as well as in android. First i want to try it in android.

I don't want to save the detail in server. I heard about node.js and socket.io, is this idea possible through these libraries?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can send data using **SOCKET** below link is example of socket in android.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html

And for continuously sending data you should Use AlramManger with Intent Service which send location in background below link for that.

http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/

EDIT

if you dont want to use SOCKET then one alternative is **GCM**. it is also be good for your requirement but it will save push on google server and it may take some delay to arrived on device, it's depend on google server traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly communicate with another mobile even if you use GPRS service. However if the other user is in limited distance like 10 meter then you may use Bluetooth or Wifi.

You must required a service in case you want to communicate with remote user. The alternate you can use is SMS service but it is going to cost you a lot and it has limitation in number of sending SMS for a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concept of GCM which requires device id of different people who want to communicate... Using this concept you can send push notification to receiver...
Below is the link... [GCM](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)